# Update ResultSet with Spring JDBCTemplate

Tags: java, spring, jdbctemplate

With `Spring boot 1.5.8.RELEASE`, using `org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate` I want to query `SELECT id, name FROM user`, then update while iterating over all results.

With classic JDBC code, I used to use:

```
PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql,
      ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
...
rs.updateString("name", "toto");
...
```

But how do that with Spring JDBCTemplate class (query method)?

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#query-org.springframework.jdbc.core.PreparedStatementCreator-org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowCallbackHandler-: you pass a PreparedStatementCReator that creates the statement as above, and a RowCallbackHandler which does what you want with the ResultSet.

Comment: thanks you, I tried with the factory: ``new PreparedStatementCreatorFactory(sql).newPreparedStatementCreator(new Object[]{ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE})`` but it seems not like that :/

Comment: Just use a lambda: `PreparedStatementCreator psc = conn -> { // create your prepared statement here }`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @JB Nizet:

```
jdbcTemplate.query(new PreparedStatementCreator() {
            @Override
            public PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(Connection con) throws SQLException {
                return con.prepareStatement("SELECT id, slug FROM user", ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
            }
        }, new ResultSetExtractor<Void>() {
            @Override
            public Void extractData(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException, DataAccessException {

                while (rs.next()) {

                        rs.updateString("slug", artistSlug);

                }

                return null;
            }
        });
```